# How does this code works ( for loop in python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was going through some Kaggle courses for certification. In Intermediate machine learning tutorial I bumped on this *for* loop. I know how for loop works but this *for* loop is different.

```
# Get names of columns with missing values
cols_with_missing = [col for col in X_train.columns
                     if X_train[col].isnull().any()]

# Drop columns in training and validation data
reduced_X_train = X_train.drop(cols_with_missing, axis=1)
reduced_X_valid = X_valid.drop(cols_with_missing, axis=1)
```

you can see in col_with_missing variable.

1. what that for loop is doing inside the bracket and why *col* is called before for statement.
2. Also in if statement if we are calling X_train[col] data then how *reduced_X_valid* variable work because it is getting wrong data.

Comment: Its called list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the `list comprehension`. You iterate over data structure such as list and you can modify all elements of it, or choose them based on specified conditions. The most basic list comprehension looks like that

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [x for x in a] # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

We can add a condition

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [x for x in a if x < 3] # [1, 2]
```

Comment: @Ayush Also note that cols_with_missing is getting the columns with Nan or missing values using the list comprehension described above. While reduced_X_train drops those columns that were selected by cols_with_missing . This explains why  reduced_X_train has reduced column. Best

Comment: yeah I got that but why reduced_x_valid is going through the same iteration.